# Nest retries when using multiple nodes behind load balancer

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, retry-logic

In the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/retries.html) of Nest v7, we can find:

> By default, NEST will retry a request as many times as there are nodes in the cluster, **that the client knows about**

I'm instantiating the `ElasticClient` as follows:

```cs
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(configuration.BaseUrl))
    .BasicAuthentication(configuration.User, configuration.Password)
    .EnableApiVersioningHeader()
    .ThrowExceptions();

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

The `configuration.BaseUrl` has the following format:

> https://elasticsearch.service:9200/

It's basically an address to a Kubernetes service. Behind that service there are 4 replicas of elasticsearch.

I wonder, do retries work in this case? Does Nest discover that there are 4 replicas, and does it send up to 4 retries?

If it doesn't, what should I do to enable that? Do I need to expose each replica under seperate service and use that to initialize the client? Or maybe, should I just use Polly instead?

Comment: I don't think that NEST would auto-magically discover Kubernetes replicaset. But with minikube you could give it a try locally.